# How are column names formatted when data is loaded in DB2 from CSV?

Tags: csv, db2

I have an IBM DB2 Cloud account and I have added DB2 from the catalog. I have a schema and I was able to create a table name.
I uploaded the data from a csv which has 1 row as header with column names.

I was able to successfully upload the data into the table, but for some column names it added underscore replacing space, where as in some column names it did not replace the space or special character.

Here are the sample column names where it updated column names with underscore and columns where it did not replace and loaded name as it is in the csv file.

Column in CSV File

- School ID
- Adequate Yearly Progress Made?
- CPS Performance Policy Status
- 9th Grade EXPLORE (2009)
- 9th Grade EXPLORE (2010)
- Elementary, Middle, or High School

After data loaded to DB2 - Column name

- School_ID
- Adequate_Yearly_Progress_Made_
- CPS_Performance_Policy_Status
- 9th Grade EXPLORE (2009)
- 9th Grade EXPLORE (2010)
- Elementary, Middle, or High School

If you compare the column names in some case the special characters and spaces are replaced with underscore and in some cases the column name is same as csv file.

Why this behavior?

Comment: You question is not clear! What tool exactly are you using to load this csv data ? 
Db2 does not have a built-in utility to create a table from a csv file.  The table must exist already when loading from csv using nativle db2 utilities like IMPORT or LOAD.  I suspect this issue comes from the tool you are using.

Comment: DB2 I am using is on cloud. Where there is option to use LOAD option to upload the data. However while loading data on cloud I created a table and there is only one default column with type CHAR & size of 5. But I can still load all the data from a CSV and it will automatically creates the columns and load data into each of the column.

Comment: Add that information and more details to the question. Edit it, so that all relevant information is present. Right now it is not clear what product you are using and which steps. How does the CSV look like, does it include a header row?

Comment: Added information, hope this is clear.